# Is there an ordered thread-safe map in .NET?

Tags: .net, concurrency, skip-lists

It looks like `ConcurrentDictionary` is roughly the .NET equivalent of Java's `ConcurrentHashMap`. Is there a .NET equivalent of Java's `ConcurrentSkipListMap`? I couldn't find one.

P.S. An equivalent in terms of only interface works. An equivalent in implementation (a skip list) also works.

Comment: Maybe you should explain [your real problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

There is not a dictionary built in to the .net framework that is both thread-safe and ordered.

The closest you can get is use the non-thread safe [`OrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) and you gate access to it with a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) on all reads and writes to turn it in to a thread safe collection.

Comment: To the person who down voted, please let me know why you thought my answer was not useful, I would like to correct whatever you considered wrong about it.